# NSMutableArray becomes nil when sent to main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsmutablearray, null

I have a function on a background thread that looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *descriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *description = [flickrFetcher descriptionForPhotoID:[[photos objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]];
    if ([description length] == 0) {
        description = @"No description available.";
    }
[descriptions addObject:description];
NSLOg(@"descriptions:%@.", descriptions);
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:action withObject:descriptions];
```

In action:

```
NSLog(@"description now is:%@.", descriptions");
```

Logs:

```
    Descriptions:2011-12-22 15:13:29.265 Paparazzi[3683:11903] (
    "No description available.",
    "No description available.",
    "No description available.",
    "No description available.",
     "No description available.",
     "No description available.",
    "No description available.",
    "No description available.",
    "This is a photo of just the eyes of an image I created by editing Apple's snow leopard image. I call the whole image \"Thermal Leopard\"."
).

descriptions:(null).
```

In that function, descriptions (the array) always ends up as nil. Why is this happening?

**EDIT 1:**

The second time I call this function, the array is not nil and every thing works as expected. It is just the first time this code is called. Also, it is only nil in the main thread action method, not in the code shown above.

**EDIT 2:**

Is this a bug? Should I submit it to Apple?
I think this might not be my fault, if I could get suggestions on wether this is a bug or not that would be great.

Comment: What does "action" look like?

Comment: - (void)dataLoadedForDescriptions:(NSMutableArray *)descriptions;

Comment: Are-you sure that `dataLoadedForDescriptions:` isn't invoked in another place than this code?

Comment: I am Positive. I have checked this many times.

Comment: You should consider pasting logs in here. Someone may see something you missed.Pls direct copy/paste (no edits). Something like this will do in each of the two methods: `NSLog(@"%s -> %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,descriptions)`

Comment: What happens if you send a copy of the mutableArray to the main thread?

Comment: So your problem is somewhere in the creation of your array. My guess is that you are trying to add a nil object to your mutable array at some point inside your loop.

Comment: By the way I have created a sample project with an NSOperation object, added it to the queue and performed a similar operation to that of your code above and the mutable array is sent to the main thread as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Somewhere in the action method, I found that I was setting description to nil. Thank you all soooo much for your help. I am upvoting all of your answers and comments to thank you.